# проблема с многопоточностью в сортировке строк не правильная сортировка

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

проблема с многопоточностью в сортировке строк не правильная сортировка

```
// создание потоков

procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
begin
  chez := 0;
  chez2 := 0;
  c := -1;
  working := True;
  SetLength(thread_mass, Form1.SpinEdit.Value);
  for i := 0 to Form1.SpinEdit.Value -1 do
  begin
    thread_mass[i] := Potok.Create(True);
   thread_mass[i].Priority := tpNormal;
    thread_mass[i].FreeOnTerminate := True;
    thread_mass[i].Resume;
  end;
end;

// главный поток

procedure Potok.Execute;
begin
  while working do //работаем пока переменная равна тру
  begin
    try
      CS.Enter; //вход в критическую секцию
      Inc(c); // переменная глобальная накручивается чтоб посчитать количество потоков
      if c < Filez.Count then  //условие условие сравнивает количество потоков и количество строк в глобальном объекте Filez  
        potz := c // записываем данные с глобальной переменной в переменную которую я создал в классе самого потока
      else working := False; // если условие не выполнено то выходим из цикла
    finally // заставляем потоки покинуть секцию
      CS.Leave; // выход из критической секции
    end;
    if working then // проверяем цикл закончился или нет
    begin
      if pos('vasy',LowerCase(Filez.Strings[potz]))<> 0 then // проверка имени в строке 
      begin
        rez := 1; 
      Sleep(3);
      end
      else if pos('misha',LowerCase(Filez.Strings[potz]))<>0 then // проверка имени в строке
      begin
        rez := 1;
        Sleep(3);
      end
      else if pos('petia',LowerCase(Filez.Strings[potz]))<>0 then // проверка имени в строке
      begin
        rez := 1;
        Sleep(3);
      end
      else if pos('lexa',LowerCase(Filez.Strings[potz]))<>0 then // проверка имени в строке
      begin
        rez := 1;
        Sleep(3);
      end
      else  // любые другие имена 
      begin
        rez := 2;
        Sleep(3);
      end;
      Synchronize(Synhz); // синхонизируем данные
    end;
  end;
end;


//дальше синхронизация так как будем работать c vcl и ее глобальными переменными,объектами изменять их

procedure Potok.Synhz;
begin
  case rez of
  1:begin
      inc(chez); // это счетчик глобальной переменной что вывести данные в лейбл
       rus_D.Add(Filez.Strings[potz]);  // дабавление имен в глобальный объект с индексом переменной класса самого потока 
      Form1.Label4.Caption := IntToStr(chez); // вывод самого счетчика
    end;
  2:begin
      inc(chez2); //это другой счетчик глобальной переменной что вывести данные лейбл
      ether_D.Add(Filez.Strings[potz]); // дабавление имен в глобальный объект с индексом переменной класса самого потока 
      Form1.Label12.Caption := IntToStr(chez2); // вывод самого счетчика
    end;
  end;
end;
```

собственно в чем ошибка при сортировке имен и добавление в объект rus_D русских имен, попадаются английские, которые должны попадать в

объект ether_D,я так понимаю это связанно что я не обезопасил потоки,но с виду не вижу не какой ошибки буду очень признателен за разьяснение

что я делаю не так и как нужно

**Update**

```
var // глобально объявлена CS: TCriticalSection;
// инициализируется при создании формы 
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CS := TCriticalSection.Create; 
end;
```

---

```
type
  Potok = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations } 
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure Synhz;
  public
    potz: Integer; //вот здесь объявлен
   { Public declarations } 
  end;
```

Comment: Список `Filez` после старта потоков модифицируется?

Comment: Критическая секция где объявлена и инициализирована?

Comment: Filez не модифицируется

implementation

<br>var
<br>CS: TCriticalSection;

<br>procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
<br>begin
 <br>Filez := TStringList.Create;
<br>end;

Comment: А `potz` где объявлена?

Answer (score 2):

Rez у вас глобальная переменная. И в эту переменную вы пишете из разных потоков? Между записью и синхронизацией проходит несколько миллисекунд и пара переменных rez и potz не "указывают" на один и тот же объект.

На самом деле я бы делал по другому.

1. Конкретному экземпляру потока даешь задание (проверить с i до j).
2. Поток проверяет и раскидывает в две глобальные (не визуальные) переменные  rus_D и ether_D. Запись в глобальные переменные в критической секции (*если объекты потоково безопасны, то можно без секции*?). Изменение глобальных указателей, счетчиков тоже в той же критической секции (тут можно провести аналогию с транзакциями). Проверка и работа с локальными переменными вне критической секции, запись в глобальные переменные в критической.
3. Вне потока (по завершении) визуализируем rus_D и ether_D.

Нужно тщательно следить за использованием глобальных переменных. Всегда существует вероятность, что даже такая простая операция как i:=i+1 будет одновременно запущена в двух потоках и вместо ответа 2 мы получим 1.

Comment: Ну можно rez также в массив разместить, то есть для каждого потока свой результат. На строках, кстати, не думаю, что вообще многопоточность оправдана. Даже 1000 файлов  в один поток обработается быстрее, чем 10 с потоками.